# sql query to exclude not null columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, null

I have below table and records

```
create table emp_details(empno int primary key,enname varchar(22),sal int,comm int);
insert into emp_details values(1,'ram',4500,200);
insert into emp_details(empno,enname) values(2,'kumar');
insert into emp_details(empno)values(3);
```

Now i do not want to display the rows having null values in the columns except primary key column.

```
Excepted output

Empno     Ename         Sal   Comm
1         ram           4500  200
2         kumar
```

I used below query to arrive the above result.

```
select * from emp_details where empno  not in(select empno from emp_details
where enname is  null and sal is  null and comm is  null)
```

But my orginal table having 72 columns how can i check all the columns for getting above result.

/

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to determine that all 72 columns are NULL but without typing all 72 column names?

Comment: I'd question why you have a table where all 71 columns are defined as `NULL`able (excluding the PK, which doesn't really count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the length of `CONCAT` this way (but it treats empty strings and NULLs the same):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.emp_details
  WHERE LEN(CONCAT(Sal,Comm,...70 more columns)) > 0;
```

You could build that `CONCAT` list this with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @cols nvarchar(max);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT N',' + name FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.emp_details')
    AND name NOT IN (N'empno', N'enname')
    ORDER BY column_id
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'');
  
SET @sql = N'SELECT empno, enname, ' + @cols
  + ' FROM dbo.emp_details WHERE LEN(CONCAT(' + @cols + ')) > 0;';
  
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=88b005fcb0d5528d980d70503b8322b8)